# LibGDX - track tap event on touch

Tags: java, input, libgdx, toggle

I'm relatively new to LibGDX and bumped into some buggy situation.
I'm creating a 2D game and would like to make my sound effects toggle on and off when I click on the rectangle.

```
 private boolean soundOn = true;
 private Rectangle soundRect;
 private Vector2 touchPoint;

 public Constructor(){
     soundRect = new Rectangle();
     touchPoint = new Vector2(0, 0);
 }

 public void update(float delta){       
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touchPoint = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
            soundRect = new Rectangle(83, 0, 78, 63);
            if (soundRect.contains(touchPoint)) {
                soundOn = false;
            }
        }
 }
```

I have also tried this method, but it does not seem to work either.

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
         touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());

        if ((touchPoint.x >= soundRect.x) &&

                (touchPoint.y >= soundRect.y) && 
                (touchPoint.x <= soundRect.x + soundRect.width)&&           (touchPoint.y <= soundRect.y + soundRect.height)) {
                    Gdx.app.log("sound", "toggles");
                    soundOn = false;
                }
    }
```

I know the code is not finished, it should be able to switch back to true, but for now it doesn't even switch to false;

Comment: By any chance, did you forget to finish the question in the bottom? Since it ends to `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use implement InputProcessor class and register it through                `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()`

Or you should track tap movement using GestureAdapter

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureAdapter(){
        @Override
        public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {

             //here you can write code for touch event.
              return true;
        }

    }));
```

these line should be present in constructor or show method.

Comment: oh so apparently I am completely dumb, the problem was I had a whole class implementing the InputProcessor, however I did not use that at all & did not expect it would cause this sort of bug... BUT. I have tried this as well & works great, thanks for showing me this new method!!